# Images delete function with ID

Tags: php

I try to delete image in my images directory but still not happen with my image file.
I try to use with this code:

```
<a href=\"../admin/core/de_products.php?id=$row[id]\">Delete</a>
```

with this function:

```
<?php
require_once("../inc/con_db.php");

if(isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"]!="")
{

$image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='".$_GET["id"]."'") or die(mysql_error());`

    if(mysql_num_rows($image)>0)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($image);
        $image_name=$row["img_thumb"];`

        $check=mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE id='".$_GET["id"]."'") or die(mysql_error());

        if($check)
        {
            @unlink("images/products/thumbs/".$image_name);
            echo "Database has been deleted!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Oops, there is some problem";
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: be aware of `"DELETE FROM products WHERE id='".$_GET["id"]."'"`!!! It's not safe!

Comment: 1. be aware of sql injection attacks ! 2.make sure that unlink function is reached (check if "Database has been deleted!" is printet) 3. remove the @ charachter from unlink , enable all php errors and warnings and update your posts with all errors

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any warnings or errors on the page or in your server logs? I suggest you remove the @ from in front of unlink until you have finished debugging this problem so that you can actually see the warnings it is likely throwing.

You might try checking that the .../thumbs/ directory is writable by whatever user your server is running as. Or, you can just set its permissions to 777 if you're lazy like me. To delete a file, you need write permissions on the directory in which it resides.

Comment: No, I have no warning or error, the massage appear: Database has been deleted!

Comment: I'm assuming this is not on an actual people-can-see-it kind of site and is more of a learning project, right?

In any case, you should consider not writing the queries like you are, or at least use mysql_real_escape_string on the id before passing it to MySQL.

Comment: when i have removed @ from unlink I got error massage:
Warning: unlink(images/products/thumbs/2.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in D:\MyWebSite\css_pro\admin\core\de_products_test.php on line 17

Comment: @Kim, that @ hides your error which means error still occurs.

Comment: Ah, so that message is saying that images/products/thumbs/2.jpg doesn't exist, which could also mean that you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out. Could you please click the check mark to accept my answer if it helped you? Thanks.